# Help me with construction of this interrogative sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

***Why did you not tell the truth? Can you tell me?***

Now join them in one sentence. What is the result?

**Can you tell me why did you not tell the truth?**

or

**Can you tell me why you did not tell the truth?**

I'm guessing the second one should be correct. You did something i.e. hide the truth and I'm asking you the reason behind it. **Can you tell me why(the reason for which) you did not tell the truth?**

Right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is certainly *textbook* English, but the first sentence isn't actually *wrong* -- at least if you add a comma after "me"

> Can you tell me why you did not tell the truth?
>   Can you tell me, why **did you not** tell the truth?
>
> Could you tell me where **you put** the TV remote?
>   Could you tell me, where **did you put** the TV remote?
>
> Could you tell me where in the store **I might** find light bulbs?
>   Could you tell me, where in the store **might I** find light bulbs?

The second form is a little more formal and so is less common, but it's a valid alternate way to form the question.

Comment: Sorry, which one is  *more formal* ? the first one or the second?

Comment: @user118494  the second one.  I've edited my answer.